# Check when a list is fully rendered with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an ul that loads data from an array using a ng-repeat. The array is pretty big and the load of the list lasts too much.

I want to put a loader so its shown at the begining of the loading and hides just, and this is the important part, when that ul is fully rendered in the html.
My problem is that I can’t find a way to throw a function when the ul is fully rendered.

The way I have this right now is:

Controller:

```
function renderMatters() {
    api_horus.getMatters()
        .success(function (data) 
        {
               $scope.matters = data.matters;
          }

        })
        .error(function (error) {
            status = 'Unable to load matters data: ' + error.message;
        });

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-model="matters" class="list clearfix" ng-class="{'floatingList':isHorizontal}">
      <li ng-repeat="matter in filtered = (matters | filter:searchText) class="matter_grid_li">
```

…

I’ve tried these possible solutions already:

**1. Using ngRoute and $viewContentLoaded:**

In angular-directive.js

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    App.initComponent();
    alert("Loaded");
});
```

This works, but the alert is not thrown when the  is fully loaded, but half way of it more or less.

**2. Using a template, ng-include and onload**

I put the ul in a different file and call it as a template

```
<div ng-include src="'template/test-loading.html'" onload="alert(‘ends’);"></div>
```

It does not work either. The alert shows at the middle of the load.
I even tried putting the ng-repeated li as the template instead of the ul because I read that the onload is thrown only when the PARENT element is loaded. Not success either.

---

How can I know when an element is fully rendered in HTML?

Tx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a callback inside the componentInit function?

Comment: you can use `$last` to detect rendering of your last element. so on bases of `$last` you can do what you want

Comment: From a UX perspective, if the list is large enough, you should probably try some form of pagination, which would also reduce the amount of time spent to render a page

Comment: I have tried a callback inside the function, but I don't need to know when the function ends, I got that. The thing is that the render in HTML lasts way more than that. I need to know the end of the ul render

Comment: I like the last approach. Not super clean, but it could work, gonna check

Comment: No pagination, tx

Answer (score 0):

just create one div with

```
<div ng-if="showMsg">{{msg}}</div>
<div ng-if="!showmMsg">
<ul ng-model="matters" class="list clearfix" ng-class="     {'floatingList':isHorizontal}">
  <li ng-repeat="matter in filtered = (matters | filter:searchText) class="matter_grid_li"></div>
```

In controller :

```
 $scope.showMsg = true;
 $scope.msg = "loading...";
 function renderMatters() {
    api_horus.getMatters()
       .success(function (data) 
       {
           $scope.matters = data.matters;
            $scope.showMsg = false;
            $timeout(angular.noop)
       }

    })
    .error(function (error) {
        status = 'Unable to load matters data: ' + error.message;
    });

   }
```

Comment: This is going to wait until the function renderMatters finishes, but when it does, the list in HTML is not fully loaded yet